# Why does searchview only outputs the first item on the listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, searchview

I have a listview with custom rows within it. Whenever I use filter on my searchview, only the first item shows up whenever it could filter something. I use Arrays to store the data.

Ex.

```
items: A, B, C
```

If I search for 'A', it shows up 'A' (The first data, or in this case, row), and whenever I search for 'B' or 'C', it still shows up 'A'. Then whenever I search for anything other than the items for example 'H', it does not show up anything (which is correct).

I would like to search them, by the contact's name "mContact".

These are my codes:

**MainActivity.java**

```
ListView listView;
    TextView totalText;

    String currency = "₱";
    String mContact[] = {"Craig", "Agatha", "Dave", "Brandon", "Russel", "Gleceper", "Percy", "Test"};
    double mDebt[] = {2000, 525, 8000, 5000, 955, 4000, 50123, 51247};
    double mDebtTotal = 0;
    String mDesc[] = {"This is a description... etc", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
    String mDate[] = {"Apr. 21, 2016", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
    int mImg[] = {R.drawable.debtcontact_craig, R.drawable.debtcontact_agatha, R.drawable.debtcontact_dave, R.drawable.debtcontact_brandon, R.drawable.debtcontact_russel, R.drawable.debtcontact_gleceper, R.drawable.debtcontact_lola, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background};

    MyAdapter adapter;

    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.##");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* Set text of Total based on total amt of mDebt*/
        totalText = findViewById(R.id.TotalTextView);
        for (double x: mDebt) { //Compute total mDebt
            mDebtTotal += x;
        }
        if (mDebtTotal == 0){ //If mDebtTotal == 0
            totalText.setText("Create a debt with an amount first.");
        } else {
            totalText.setText("Total: " + currency + " " + formatter.format(mDebtTotal));
        }


        /* Display contents of listview*/
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, mContact, mDebt, mDesc, mDate, mImg);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                makeDialog(mContact[i], mDebt[i], mDesc[i], mDate[i]);
            }
        });

    }

    class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        Context context;
        String rContact[];
        double rDebt[];
        String rDesc[];
        String rDate[];
        int rImg[];

        MyAdapter(Context c, String contact[], double debt[], String desc[], String date[], int img[]){
            super(c, R.layout.listview_row, R.id.Contact, contact);
            this.context = c;
            this.rContact = contact;
            this.rDebt = debt;
            this.rDesc = desc;
            this.rDate = date;
            this.rImg = img;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, parent, false);
            ImageView images = row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            TextView myContact = row.findViewById(R.id.Contact);
            TextView myDebt = row.findViewById(R.id.Debt);
            TextView myDesc = row.findViewById(R.id.Desc);
            TextView myDate = row.findViewById(R.id.Date);

            images.setImageResource(rImg[position]);
            myContact.setText(rContact[position]);
            myDebt.setText(currency + " " + formatter.format(rDebt[position])); /* Adds currency at the beginning */
            myDesc.setText(rDesc[position]);

            myDate.setText(rDate[position]);

            return row;
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity.java SearchView**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.app_searchbutton);
        searchItem.getActionView();

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setQueryHint("Enter a contact e.g 'Robert'");
        searchView.setIconified(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayAdapter creates a copy of the array sent in the constructor and uses that copy going forward for all operations. So when you call filter(), that copy is modified not the rContact array. So when the adapter decides to show only 1 item in the list, you populate the first item from rContact which is always "A".

Replace

```
myContact.setText(rContact[position]);
```

with

```
myContact.setText(getItem[position]);
```

But you would have to think of a way to populate the right data in other fields yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it now replaces the contact name with the correct search filter, but the Image stays the same (references the first row), as well as the description, and date. I tried replacing the code for each of them but the app would crash.

Comment: You'd either need to use a BaseAdapter and write the filter logic yourself or use some other way to correlate the name to other data